# Pycharm can't auto complete some modules

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Pycharm works well at most time. But it can't auto complete some code.

The following "objects" can't be completed. Who knows why?

I use Pycharm Community Edition and Django 2.2

```
class SnippetList(APIView):
    """
    List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """

    def get(self, request):
        snippets = Snippet.objects.all()  # The objects can't be auto completed.
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return Response(resp)
```

[image]

Power Save Mode is off.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. When you're typing, it doesn't autocomplete the word `objects`?

Comment: @SamCreamer  Yes. I use Pycharm Community Edition. I Update the not-autocomplete picture in the question.

Comment: @SamCreamer I found vscode doesn't autocomplete the word objects too. Maybe it's not pycharm's issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, it works at the objects level, deep level still not work.

```
# pip install django-stubs

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Snippet(BaseModel):

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happend if you have enabled de Power Save mode. Check the icon of a hat at the lower right corner.

[image]

Comment: Power Save Mode is off on my Pycharm, it seems not work. I use Pycharm Community Edition, is it the reason?

Comment: I use Pycharm Community Edition too. Maybe you can try a new autocomplete module named Kite, it uses AI to improve the autocomplete. 
https://kite.com/

Comment: I found vscode doesn't autocomplete the word objects too. Maybe it's not pycharm's issues.

Answer (score 0):

Django is part of the Professional Edition so you need it for completion to work.
See [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using Django.
PyCharm Community edition does not offer autocompletion on Django (I haven't used the professional version).
To use the PyCharm autocomplete, you have to use the `type hinting` feature of python, available from `python3.5` with some other features added on `python3.6`.
You can use [django-hint](https://github.com/Vieolo/django-hint) module which helps you in type hinting.
For example, if you write your model this way:

```
from django.db import models
from django_hint import StandardModelType

class Snippet(models.Model, StandardModelType):
    """Just like any other model"""
    pass
```

inherited from `StandardModelType`, while making a query, `objects` will be offered as an autocomplete. `StandardModelType` does not affect your database and does not create a migration.
Note that you need `python3.6` or higher to use `django-hint`

Disclaimer: I am the author of `django-hint`