# VSCode autocomplete for Django QuerySet.filter(property__regex='^This not autocomplete')

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, pycharm

How to autocomplete property of Django QuerySet.filter in VSCode?

Just like it works in Pycharm Professional Edition as follow,

[image]

I think it's really useful, because Django use too many python magic that will make developers confused.

I only autocomplete objects in another question [Pycharm can't auto complete some modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58625742/pycharm-cant-auto-complete-some-modules)

I want to make it more powerful. And I use Django 2.2 and Python 3.6

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shamanu4.django-intellisense

Comment: @mario_sunny  I have installed djangointellisense, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python extension for VS Code currently doesn't provide IntelliSense for anything off of `objects` as those are dynamically generated and thus require custom support to work.